# in c#: expression evaluation function like flash script

Tags: c#, eval

#### Duplicate of: [How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-expression-dynamically)

See also: [C# eval equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/c-eval-equivalent)

---

How to evaluate expression. Maybe like:

```
int a=1;
int b=3;
int c=Eval("a+b");
```

or

```
int c=int.parse("1+3*(2+3)");
```

This seems stupid to me. is it possible in c#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take code, and using the CSharpCodeProvider write an Eval function that actually compiles your code into an in-memory assembly and then executes that code.

See this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/evalcscode.aspx) for sample source.

Comment: This works, but it produces a new assembly, so while you can use it to eval logical statements, you can't use it for metaprogramming. This is coming in C#5 (see anders's PDC2008 talk on the future of C#)

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. C# contains no runtime compiler.
There is [an open source project](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-10.html) attached to Mono that will do this.

Answer (score 0):

I enumerate several different approaches that I am aware of in this [answer to "How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically/52685808#52685808) which include various .NET framework solutions such as CodeDomProvider, DataBinder.Eval, DataTable.Compute, Document.InvokeScript, and more.