# How to parse arithmetic operators from string?

Tags: c#, string, math, operation

Is it possible to assign an int variable a value that is a result of expression written in a string? E.g. I have a string "5 - 3" and the expected result is 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [in c#: expression evaluation function like flash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534894/in-c-expression-evaluation-function-like-flash-script)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string expression to Integer Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607798/).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Calculator.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2007/05/05/calculator-net-calculator-that-evaluates-math-expressions.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I believe that is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you fancy writing your own (I did, it's fun!). Have a look on Wikipedia for:

[Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm) and 
[Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

The pseudo-code is really clear and it's a great learning experience

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing built into the framework, so you can either built your own mathematical expression parser, or use one of the many libraries out there.

A search on ".net arithmetic parser" comes up with many results, some free, some not.

For instance:

- [muParser](http://muparser.sourceforge.net/)
- [Acid library](http://blueanalysis.com/acidlibrary.php)