# How to evaluate an arithmetic expression stored in a string

Tags: c#, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [in c#: expression evaluation function like flash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534894/in-c-expression-evaluation-function-like-flash-script)

I need to calculate an arithmetic expression stored in a string.

The expression contains variables, but these I could replace in advance.

I'd use the JScript eval function, but it is **deprecated** and it does not honor the current locale set for the program (being in germany my expression is e.g. "4,28*1,10" instead of "4.28*1.10").

It needs to support localization and parantheses.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because it's a lot of work, but I think your best bet is to write an arithmetic parser. A [Pratt parser](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/) would be pretty good for this job.

Comment: There are a few expression evaluators in .net (JScript, Ironpython, DataTable), is there none which can work with localisation??