# how to convert string to code in c#

Tags: c#, eval

I saw there is such question in c++
I am a very begginer and I need a very simple example how to do it .
the user writes code in the text box and what I need o do is to execute it
how???

Comment: Please see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/c-eval-equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/c-eval-equivalent).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read the properties of a C# class dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/how-can-i-read-the-properties-of-a-c-sharp-class-dynamically)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the classes in the System.CodeDom namespace to compile C# into in-memory assemblies, and run them on the fly.  [Here is a mini-tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/Run-Time_Code_Generation1.aspx).

Alternatively, you can use [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx) to construct code on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

Check the approach used in this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/evalcscode.aspx).