# Calling functions from string with parameters

Tags: c#, function

```cs
try
{
    Type type = typeof(Functions);

    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(msg);
    Functions c = new Functions();

    ParameterInfo[] pars = method.GetParameters();
    foreach (ParameterInfo p in pars)
    {
        send(p.ParameterType);
    }
    string result = (string)method.Invoke(c, null);

    send(result);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    send(ex.Message);
}
```

So **msg** is string, I want to call function with parameters, for example like this:

```cs
string msg = "print(\"yes\")";

public class Functions
{
    public string print(string text)
    {
        send(text);
    }
}
```

Currently if **msg** is equal to "print" it can execute simple **print()** function in Functions class:

```cs
public class Functions
{
    public string print()
    {
        return "print() called";
    }
}
```

[image: code]

But I don't know how to make it execute `func` with parameters, also get parameters from **msg**.

Comment: You can either parse the string yourself or use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825107/how-to-convert-string-to-code-in-c-sharp

Comment: What about [Scripting API Samples](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples)

Comment: "get parameters from msg" is way too broad - so you have to figure out exactly what your requirements are and probably ask separate question on it. "execute func with parameters" is on other hand is properly scoped for SO  and already answered in the linked duplicate.