# Implementing JS Eval in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# eval equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/c-eval-equivalent)
>
> Duplicate of [How can I evaluate C# code dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/c-eval-equivalent)

How can we Implement JS eval() in C#
If possible provide an example..
thank you

Comment: [C# eval equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/c-eval-equivalent)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/c-eval-equivalent

Comment: Can you include to project MSScript.dll, if so I would provide an answer

Comment: a = "<<x>>/100";
a.replace("<<x>>","20");
string b = eval(a);

i should get .2  as result

how can i do it in C# 

without using JScript is it possible?
to replace eval(a);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I evaluate C# code dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/how-can-i-evaluate-c-sharp-code-dynamically)

Answer (score 4):

You can actually use the JScript `eval` function from C#...

Create a file JsMath.js, with the following JScript code :

```
class JsMath
{
    static function Eval(expression : String) : double
    {
        return eval(expression);
    };
}
```

Compile it into a DLL :

```
jsc /t:library JsMath.js
```

Add a reference to JsMath.dll to your project. You can now use the JsMath class in your code :

```
double result = JsMath.Eval(expression);
```

Comment: This is very practical solution for quick evaluations in any .NET language. You just need to include a reference to Microsoft.JScript.dll also.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C# 3.0 / .NET 3.5, there's a sample of a fully operational expression parser in [*C# Samples for Visual Studio 2008*](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpsamples) at MSDN Code Gallery, under **DynamicQuery**. This makes it possible not just to evaluate single expressions, but even to create functions (delegates) from them, or LINQ expressions. (The `LinqDataSource` control uses a slightly modified version of this sample internally.)

Answer (score -1):

Go to http://json.org/ and scroll to the bottom. Look for C# in the left column.