# Instantiate a generic type from string

Tags: c#, generics, instance

I have a string containing the name of a generic class with specified type:

```
string s = "GenericRouteHandler<MemberHandler>";
```

How do I instantiate an instance from this string? I know how to instantiate a concrete class using Type.GetType() and then use Activator but I am not sure where to go with a generic class.

Comment: May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/c-eval-equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this  `typeof(GenericRouteHandler<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(MemberHandler));`

Of course if you don't have the types you have to use `Type.GetType(string)` to get the type instead of `typeof`.

**EDIT**: Then you have to activate the type `Activator.CreateInstance()` or invoke a contructor if know the signature `myGenericType.GetConstructor(ctorArgsTypes).Invoke(ctorParams);` ; it can be faster if cache the consturctors it can be faster then Activator.CreateInstance()

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx)