# Instantiating a generic type from string

Tags: c#, generics

I want to [Instantiate a generic type from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609969/instantiate-a-generic-type-from-string) and have done the following:

```
    private static void APERAK(string content, PartyElement pe, bool reload)
    {
        Type t = typeof(Serializer<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(GetMessageTypeVersion(content)));
        Serializer<t> serializer = new Serializer<t>();
    }

    private static string GetMessageTypeVersion(string content)
    {
        //TODO
        return "APERAK";
    }
```

But in

```
Serializer<t> serializer = new Serializer<t>();
```

it says that "The type or namespace name 't' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" before compiling. But I want to instantiate the Serializer based on the string found. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You already *have* a generic type with the following:

```
typeof(Serializer<>).MakeGenericType(...);
```

All you need to do is *instantiate* it:

```
object o = ACtivator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Of course the compiler will have no knowledge of what type `t` is, thus you will not be able to use its methods/properties without reflection, so generics doesn't really help you here.  Best you can do is cast is to a non-generic base class of `Serializer<>` (assuming one exists).

Answer (score 0):

Generics are a compile-time construct. You have to know what the type parameters are at compile time, not at runtime.

Comment: @zimdanen: Yes, you can construct them at runtime using reflection, but you won't have the compile-time strong typing of generics. **That is, you lose all the compile-time advantages of using generics in the first place**. So, not really.

Answer (score 0):

So, well, you really can't get all features of compile-time generics. Well, there are some another ways.

1) Instantiate generic type and pack it as object, then use reflection to call methods:

```
object t = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var res = (string)type.GetMethod("Do").Invoke(t, new object[] { "abc" });
```

2) Instantiate generic type and convert it to dynamic object, then just use it (you lose intellisense and compile-time checks):

```
dynamic t = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var res = (string)(t.Do("abc"));
```

3) Create temporary generict method and call it with reflection (you got intellisense and compile-time checks):

```
public static string UseSerializer<T>(Serializer<T> s)
{
   return s.Do("abc");
}
```

And then use it in such way:

```
var useSerializer = typeof(SomeStaticClass).GetMethod("UseSerializer")
object t = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var res = useSerializer.Invoke(null, new object[]{t});
```

In addition, this methods can be sorted by time that they are executed: dynamic < temporary method < simpleReflection