# C# execute variable code

Tags: c#, variables, dynamic, execute

Is it possible to execute code from a string variable, like:
   string mystring = "Console.WriteLine(\"Hi\");";
Is it possible to execute the contents of mystring (printing 'Hi')?

Comment: With questions like this it's a good idea to explain why you want this behavior since it's clearly not common. By doing so there is a chance someone may suggest a more elegant solution that produces the more specific behavior you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually, I'd quite like an answer to this also. I've been thinking for a while about writing an Python prompt style thing for C# using reflection or similar. I know that some exist, but using one which has been written already isn't really a great learning exercise - one of the reasons I refuse to use any libraries outside of .net in my applications - I like to learn things myself.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible using the System.Reflection.Emit or System.CodeDom namespaces, but it's not exactly a good idea as there's no mechanism to control what namespaces are and are not allowed.  A user could build a string that would wipe your hard drive.

eval()-like functions are huge gaping security holes and should be avoided.  The preferred alternative is a [DSL (domain specific language)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/YourFirstDSL.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Fire up the compiler at runtime and pass in your code. It will spit out executable code. See the [`System.CodeDom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx) namespace, especially, [`System.CodeDom.Compiler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Code DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Need to use reflection to get something like that. C# is not dynamic or interpreted language, so you dont get it out of the box

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Expr.aspx

[How can I evaluate C# code dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/c-eval-equivalent)