# C# eval code from string

Tags: c#, .net, string, function, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# eval equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/c-sharp-eval-equivalent)

Some languages like Perl or JavaScript have cool (although not fast) *eval* function for running code from string.

**Does .NET has some king of that functionality for C# ?**

**Is there anything that offers interface like this:**

```
    var e = new Evaluator("C#");
    e.Eval("int a=3; Console.Writeline(\"{0}\", a); return 123;");
    int x = (int)e.Result;
```

**?**

Comment: Have a look at the Roslyn Project too

Comment: Next to the answers you'll get you might have a look at the beta version of Roslyn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn

Comment: Look at Flee - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Flee.aspx

Comment: This question should be reopened, as the duplicate question is 3 years old and new technology Roslyn exists already as answer to this question.