# Excecute A C# Command that Stored in String Variable?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# eval equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/c-sharp-eval-equivalent)

Is it possible to Execute a C# command that is stored in a string variable

a thing like Dynamic query in SqlServer

Comment: I doubt that would be possible since the string wouldn't get parsed until after the program has been compiled

Comment: @xbonez:  It's possible to emit your own IL and execute it so I would say it's most definitely possible.

Comment: This might look like a duplicate, but the older question specifically asks about C# 2.0, for which the answer is "no". I don't think this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into the current version of .NET that allows this. However the [Roslyn project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx) aims to specifically enable scenarios like this. They have a [CTP out](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27746).

A simple example, (from [Kirill Osenkov's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2011/10/18/roslyn-ctp.aspx)), is:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SimpleEvaluationUsingScriptEngine()
{
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngine();
    int result = engine.Execute<int>("1 + 2");
    Assert.AreEqual(3, result);
}
```

Comment: This seems outside the scope of Roslyn, which is just code analysis

Comment: @Chris, actually Roslyn aims to provide full REPL / scripting capabilities, amongst other things. Check out some of the links.

Comment: Ok, cool. I feel like the scope of Roslyn keeps changing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) to compile source code from a file or from strings into an assembly you can load. Then you can invoke the generated classes via reflexion.