# String as variable name

Tags: c#

is it possible in C# to use a String like a variable name ?
I have got a:

```
String x = "matrix1_2";
Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape y = ???;
```

??? - there should be the name of variable...matrix1_2

Comment: I think you are confusing the name and the value of a variable. Or I'm confused.

Comment: It's *possible* using reflection, but it's not a good idea, usually. What do you want to achieve? There's probably a better way.

Comment: possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/c-sharp-eval-equivalent

Comment: Can you explain what you need this for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can't, and it makes no sense honestly to have a feature like that.

If you need to dynamically assign some data with key and value, you could use an dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, RectangleShape> shapes = new Dictionary<string, RectangleShape>();
shapes.Add("matrix1_2", new RectangleShape( ... ));
```

Then you can simply read the "variable" like

```
shapes["matrix1_2"]
```

Comment: Got it...I love you!...t need this!...Thanks so much!

Comment: @hradecek If you feel your question has been answered you can "accept" it by clicking on the check sign to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

You can't have dynamic variable names in C#, VB.NET or any .NET language. There is no support for such a feature.

Comment: Roslyn supports variable access like this, but other than that, this is correct.

Comment: @McKay - Roslyn is a very different matter. It is **not** C#.

Comment: @Oded, it's certainly not the best way to do it I don't think but if he knows what assembly the variable resides in he ought to be able to use reflection, right?

Comment: @BrandonMoore - reflection is not the same as declaring a variable name in runtime.

Comment: @Oded Roslyn is a different matter, but it is available in C# (CTP)

Comment: @Oded I didn't think he wanted to declare variable at runtime, but just access them by name at runtime.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question though...

Comment: @Oded Right, that would solve his problem were it possible.  It looks like what is actually has right now though is a variable that holds variable names... so maybe reflection is a possibility though it would require a workaround to account for the fact that reflection doesn't access method variables (as StriplingWarrior just pointed out on my answer).

Comment: @BrandonMoore - He probably just needs a collection but doesn't know how to express that.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not. If "matrix1_2" is a local variable, then you can't do it as the variable might not even *exist* after the compiler is through, if it is actually an instance field, then reflection may help:

```
object value = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName).GetValue(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bad idea. Try with enums or own datatypes /classes

Answer (score 0):

You could with reflection, but I suspect in this case theere is a better design you could implement that would be better than using reflection.  If you provide a little more info probably one of us could help you with that.

Declare a dictionary variable:

```
Dictionary<string, RectangleShape> rectangleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, RectangleShape>();
```

Then, where you would normallay write "matrix1_2 = somevalue;", instead write:

```
rectangleDictionary.add("matrix1_2", somevalue)
```

Then you'll be able to work with the variable name:

```
rectangleDictionary["matrix1_2"] = someothervalue;
rectangleDictionary["matrix1_2"].someproperty = something;

Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape y = rectangleDictionary["matrix1_2"];
```

Comment: Probably there is a way to do what you want by using a Dictionary<> object to store the keys and values in.

Comment: Reflection does not allow access to variables within a method: only methods, fields, types, and properties.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior That certainly does complicate the matter, though that could probably be worked around... definitely not worth working around though as I'm sure there are better options for his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does "matrix1_2" exist already? In other words, when you say y = ??? are you trying to access an existing variable or create one.

To my knowledge, there is no way to create a new "named" instance at run-time. However, you can retrieve the names of existing fields and select them using System.Reflection.

```
String x = "matrix1_2";
Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape y;
Type type = typeof(MyType); // Get type pointer
FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
foreach (var field in fields)
{
        if (field.Name == "matrix1_2")
        {
            y = field;
        }
}
```

`MyType` above is the name of whatever class `matrix1_2` lives in.

Comment: What if matrix1_2 isn't in a class, it's just a variable in the method?

Comment: @McKay - I do not believe that variable names are preserved inside a method. Once you compile down to CIL bytecode they are referenced by position (eg. V_0, V_1, V_2, etc) and whatever name you gave them is lost. So, even if you were able to dynamically create a new local variable, it would take some deep magic to refer to it in your C# programs. You might be able to use [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (perhaps with [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/)

Comment: That is precisely my point. He wants to access a theoretically arbitrary variable. If it's a field, this code will work, if it's a property, other code will work, if it's a parameter, other code could work. You don't have a very generalized solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a field value from a dynamic type in this manner (using C# in a Silverlight 5 project).

```
Type itemType = item.GetType();
try
{
    PropertyInfo field = itemType.GetProperty(fieldName);
    object val = field.GetValue(item, null);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // field doesn't exist, do something else
}
```

*Where "item" is a dynamic type generated at runtime (but doesn't have to be) and "fieldName" is a string for the property name you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a string in `Control.Find` function like below statement.

```
ComboBox comboBoxElement  = (ComboBox)this.Controls.Find("comboBoxNameThatYouSearch", true)[0];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).