# Create Control using loop then append name with string

Tags: c#

does anyone knows how to append a string to a variable name?

```
public void editForm(DataGridView dg)
{
   for(int i=0; i<=dg.Columns.Count-1;i++)
   {
      TextBox txt=new TextBox();   //I want to append i to txt. like -->TextBox txt&i
   }
}
```

Then I'll add the textboxes created to a Form.

Comment: Why not an array or list of TextBox? i.e. List<TextBox> list; and then list.Add(new TextBox());

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183041/string-as-variable-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible in `C#`.

You can achieve something similar using some sort of collection, like an array,

```
public void editForm(DataGridView dg)
{
    TextBox[] textBoxes = new TextBox[dg.Columns.Count];
    for(int i = 0; i <= dg.Columns.Count-1; i++)
    {
        textBoxes[i] = new TextBox();  
    }
}
```

Although, you could something nicer using `Enumerable.Range`,

```
public void editForm(DataGridView dg)
{
    var textBoxes = 
        Enumerable.Range(0, dg.Columns.Count)
                  .Select(i => new TextBox())
                  .ToArray();
}
```

Either way, you can then add your text boxes to the form.