# How can i construct a variable name in code from a string?

Tags: c#

I have a number of variables named test1....test10 they are all declared as a string.

what I want to do is access them from inside a loop using the loop counter something like this:

```
string test1;
//...
string test10;

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    test + i.ToString() = "some text";  
}
```

any idea how I could do this? 
this is a WPF .net 4 windows App.

Comment: Refactor to make a collection of values instead.

Comment: I suggest you get a good C# book.

Comment: What about using a list of strings instead? Are you binding these strings?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4637/785966

Comment: That doesn't work in compiled languages. Use a `List<>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple answer: don't have 10 variables, have one variable which is a collection:

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    test.Add("some text");
}
```

Having lots of variables which logically form a collection is a design smell.

(If you *really* have to do this, you could use reflection. But please don't.)

Comment: I'm wondering why you are getting more and more reputation while my answer is posted at the same time. Must have something to do with the herd instinct.

Comment: @FelixK.: On the contrary, this answer has gained me precisely 0 reputation :) More seriously, there may be part herd instinct and part due to bringing up the fact that it's a design problem.

Answer (score 4):

You simply can't, use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) or a [String-Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for this purpose.

### List

```
List<String> myStrings = new List<String>();
for (Int32 i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    myStrings.Add("some text");
}
```

### String-Array

```
String[] myStrings = new String[10];
for (Int32 i = 0; i < myStrings.length; i++) 
{
    myStrings[i] = "some text";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding them to an array of `string[]` or simply create a `List<string> list = new List<string>();`.

With the `list`, you can iterate easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible, unless you use the `dynamic` keyword, and then you will get a property instead of a true variable. Take a look at [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx), it will allow you to add properties based on a string variable.

In your case, as other have said, you really should use a `List<string>`

Comment: Pointing out dynamic or ExpandoObject to an obvious beginner is like giving them a big red button and then saying they shouldn't push it. (I'm not downvoting, because it's technically correct, but still.)

Answer (score 0):

For something as simple as 10 items, an array is the best way to go. Fast and easy.