# Is there a tool for parsing a string to create a C# func?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, function, string-parsing

I need to know if there is any library out there that will allow me to, given a certain string representing a mathematical function, say, `x^2+x+1`, (don't care about how the string format, any will work for me) generates a C# func that will represent said function.

Comment: Are you talking about something like an `eval` function for C#? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/how-can-i-read-the-properties-of-a-c-sharp-class-dynamically http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11939/Evaluate-C-Code-Eval-Function

Comment: No, I am talking about a library that for example takes the string: x^2+x+1 and generate a c# func that given X evaluate it accordingly.

Comment: I mean PARSING MATHEMATICAL FUNCTIONS TO FUNC IN C#.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Been using FLEE (Fast Lightweight Expression Evaluator) for a while now and it's been working great.  They have a version that maintains most functionality for Silverlight as well.  It's designed to do pretty much exactly what you're asking for and more.

http://flee.codeplex.com/

> Flee is an expression parser and evaluator for the .NET framework. It
>   allows you to compute the value of string expressions such as sqrt(a^2
>   + b^2) at runtime. It uses a custom compiler, strongly-typed expression language, and lightweight codegen to compile expressions
>   directly to IL. This means that expression evaluation is extremely
>   fast and efficient.

Given your example from your comment to evaluate `x^2+x+1` (written in Notepad):

```
public Func<double, double> CreateExpressionForX(string expression)
{

    ExpressionContext context = new ExpressionContext();
    // Define some variables
    context.Variables["x"] = 0.0d;

    // Use the variables in the expression
    IDynamicExpression e = context.CompileDynamic(expression);


    Func<double, double> expressionEvaluator = (double input) =>
    {
        content.Variables["x"] = input;
        var result = (double)e.Evaluate();
        return result;
    }

    return expressionEvaluator;
}



Func<double, double> expression = CreateExpressionForX("x^2 + x + 1");

double result1 = expression(1); //3
double result2 = expression(20.5); //441.75
double result3 = expression(-10.5); //121.75

Func<double, double> expression2 = CreateExpressionForX("3 * x + 10");

double result4 = expression2(1); //13
double result5 = expression2(20.5); //71.5
double result6 = expression2(-10.5); //-21.5
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [Roslyn API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113169/C-As-A-Scripting-Language-In-Your-NET-Applications). It will allow you to compile strings at runtime

Comment: nice, even though its, as far as I understand, very far from really working/being finished. Itll be interesting to see how the whole concept will integrate with the way we all use c#/vb.net

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **CSharpCodeProvider** class to compile code to a file/assembly and dynamically load the compiled assembly. Using the compiler from your program is described   [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655). This [Stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137781/c-sharp-correct-way-to-load-assembly-find-class-and-call-run-method) shows how to load the compiled assembly. Keep in mind that you need to wrap your function in a class to load and execute it later on.

Alternatively you can use [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/) to do the dirty assembly compiling, loading and executing job.

Comment: I mean PARSING MATHEMATICAL FUNCTIONS TO FUNC IN C#.

Comment: you could have mentioned this in your original question. this STILL can be solved pretty easily with expression trees, but i guess the tool provided by Chris Sinclair will do the job as good as.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) to dynamic compile a type, about this, [here](http://fluentcodedom.codeplex.com) you can find a fluent interface to simply the writing of the code, e.g:

```
var compileUnit = new FluentCodeCompileUnit()
    .Namespace("Sample1")
                .Class("Program")
                    .Method(MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Static, "Main").Parameter(typeof(string[]), "args")
                        .CallStatic(typeof(Console), "WriteLine", Expr.Primitive("Hello Fluent CodeDom"))
                    .EndMethod

                    .Method(MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Static, "Linq2CodeDomSupport").Parameter(typeof(string[]), "args")
                        .Stmt(ExprLinq.Expr(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello Linq2CodeDOM")))
                        .Declare(typeof(int), "random", ExprLinq.Expr(() => new Random().Next(10)))
                        .If((int random) => random <= 5)
                            .Stmt(ExprLinq.Expr(() => Console.WriteLine("Smaller or equal to 5.")))
                        .Else
                            .Stmt(ExprLinq.Expr(() => Console.WriteLine("Bigger than 5.")))
                        .EndIf
                    .EndMethod
               .EndClass
            .EndNamespace
        .EndFluent();

        var assembly = Helper.CodeDomHelper.CompileInMemory(compileUnit);
        assembly.GetType("Sample1.Program").GetMethod("Main").Invoke(null, new object[] { null });
```

I've to release on CodePlex a better fluent interface API that will use [Roslyn](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27744) also when it will be released in RTM.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.csscript.net/) looks like a nice solution. Of course, it also can be solved with the usage of [Expression Trees](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/09/14/generating-dynamic-methods-with-expression-trees-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) and a parse from strings to expressions, which later can be compiled (in run time), and executed.

Comment: I mean PARSING MATHEMATICAL FUNCTIONS TO FUNC IN C#.