# Is there a way to directly create a method node using C# Roslyn?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a method in a string which I assume it is well formed and works OK.. with that fact, can I simply use this string to create a node and insert it into a tree using C# Roslyn compiler?

Comment: Maybe it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864311/is-there-a-tool-for-parsing-a-string-to-create-a-c-sharp-func

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко: No; he's asking about Roslyn.

Answer (score 1):

Call [`ParseCompilationUnit`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/SyntaxFactory.cs,dcaa4aaf3f7a7628), passing `SourceCodeKind.Script` in the parse options so that a method declaration is a valid compilation unit.