# convert list of Column names to select Lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i want to simply get an lambda expression from given column names for example

```
input = "Field1,Field2"
```

output of type lambda expression for select statement:

```
x=> new { Field1 = x.Field1, Field2 = x.Field2 }
```

I do not want to use any class e.g.
x=> new <del>ClassName</del> { Field1= x.Field1, Field2= x.Field2}

without Roslyn scripting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740532/how-to-use-expression-to-build-an-anonymous-type all answers in this question are specifying the members type e.g. string for name and int for number

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019737/convert-string-to-lambda-expression-to-pass-to-linq-select/77736002#77736002 similar question