# Convert string containing bool condition to bool (C#)

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, boolean, typeconverter

I would like to convert (but i think it's not possible) a string into a bool, in this way:

```
string a = "b.Contains('!')";

private void print(string condition)
{
   string b = "Have a nice day!";

   /* Some kind of conversion here for condition parameter */
   /* like bool.Parse(condition) or Bool.Convert(condition) */

   if(condition)
   {
      Console.Write("String contains !-character.");
   }
}
```

Mind that the bool-string has to be passed to the function as a parameter.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: That string doesn't contain a bool. An example of a string that contains a bool would be "true". What you're asking is how to execute code contained in a string. That's a very different question and one you can research if you use appropriate keywords.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way to parse your string to a expression.

But of your goal is to sent the expression to an other function you could do this

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        print(x=>x.Contains("!"));
    }
    
    private static void print(Func<string,bool> condition)
    {
       string b = "Have a nice day!";

       /* Some kind of conversion here for condition parameter */
       /* like bool.Parse(condition) or Bool.Convert(condition) */

       if(condition.Invoke(b))
       {
          Console.Write("String contains !-character.");
       }
    }
}
```

if you would like a non build in way you could look at : [Is there a tool for parsing a string to create a C# func?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864311/is-there-a-tool-for-parsing-a-string-to-create-a-c-sharp-func)

Comment: Yes! I was searching exactly for something like that FLEE, but i couldn't find it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, that isn't really true - there is a built-in parser for C# code, but using it involves invoking the Roslyn compiler internals (by adding a reference to `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SCripting` and calling `CSharpScript.Evaluate...`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use an auxiliar bool variable, like this example..

```
 bool aux = false;
    private bool print(string condition)
    {
       string b = "Have a nice day!";
    
       if(b.Contains(condition))
         aux = true;
       return aux;
    }
```

Or the same example without auxiliar.

```
 private bool print(string condition)
    {
        string b = "Have a nice day!";
        return b.Contains(condition);
    }
```

Then call the method print to check if it is true or false and write the message you want

```
if(print("!"))
   Console.WriteLine("String contains !-character.");
```