# How to use a string inside the if condition in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

String value comes from a cell from database.

For example:

```
"model.Number == dtoModel.Number"
```

I want to use this string in a if condition like this;

```
if(model.Number == dtoModel.Number)
{
  //some logic
}
```

'model' and 'dtoModel' are objects of some classes.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I haved tried Expression type operators but i cant see any result in stackoverflow site.

Comment: I would say this is doable , but What exactly are you trying to achieve ? Provide more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string containing bool condition to bool (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73769645/convert-string-containing-bool-condition-to-bool-c)

Comment: You could use Roslyn (the C# compiler) programmatically for this: https://www.strathweb.com/2018/01/easy-way-to-create-a-c-lambda-expression-from-a-string-with-roslyn/

Comment: You could also make your life easier and store the expression in 3 different columns: `LeftOperandPropertyName`, `OperatorSymbol`, `RightOperandPropertyName`.

Comment: The point is though, that this is not as easy as you might expect so you should think carefully if there are easier ways to solve your problem.

Comment: If `model.Number == dtoModel.Number` (or any part of it) is a string, it should be in quotes.

Comment: Why you need that? It is certainly an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What was the real problem that you were trying to solve when you created that column?

Comment: If number is of type string, you can use Equals. Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings

Answer (score 2):

[DynamicExpresso](https://github.com/dynamicexpresso/DynamicExpresso) is a nice library that allows to execute C# expressions from a strings.

You can do:

```cs
using DynamicExpresso;
...

var interpreter = new Interpreter()
    .SetVariable("model", model)
    .SetVariable("dtoModel", dtoModel);

bool result = (bool)interpreter.Eval("model.Number == dtoModel.Number");
```

This has a performance cost so do your own research to decide if it is suitable for your application.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
if (string.Equals(model.Number, dtoModel.Number))
```

or in my case:

```
var CNF_paperFee11 = new CNF_FeeExamEntryPaper();
var CNF_paperFee22 = new CNF_FeeExamEntryPaper();
```

```
if (CNF_paperFee11.EntryKey == CNF_paperFee22.EntryKey)
```

OR

```
if (String.Equals(CNF_paperFee11.EntryKey, CNF_paperFee22.EntryKey))
```

Comment: That's not what the OP was asking: they want to go from a condition specified as string, to a real executable condition