# c# dynamically pass string method at run time for string manipulation

Tags: c#

How do I dynamically pass string methods to be applied to strings at run time. 
ex.

```
Private String Formatting(String Data, String Format)
```

When we pass `String S1 = "S1111tring Manipulation"` and `format = Remove(1,4)` - behind the scenes it becomes `S1.Remove(1,4)` resulting in "String Manipulation"

or if we pass `String  S1 = "S1111tring Manipulation"` and `format = ToLower()` behind the scene it becomes `S1.ToLower()` resulting in `"s1111tring manipulation"`

I should be able to pass any valid method like `PadLeft(25,'0')`, `PadRight`, `Replace` etc...

I would appreciate a complete example

This is what I have tried and it does not work

```
using System.Reflection;
string MainString = "S1111tring Manipulation";
string strFormat = "Remove(1, 4)";
string result = DoFormat(MainString, strFormat);

private string DoFormat(string data, string format)
        {
            MethodInfo mi = typeof(string).GetMethod(format, new Type[0]);
            if (null == mi)
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Could not find method with name '{0}'", format));

            return mi.Invoke(data, null).ToString();
        }
```

throws an error (Could not find method with name 'Remove(1, 4)') - so I am not sure how to proceed

Comment: I'm not getting you right, are you looking into passing a name of a function to a function?

Comment: You -could- mark any of the answers to your previous question as correct, or improve that question instead of asking a completely new one with the same meaning. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623436/c-sharp-call-method-based-on-contents-of-a-variable

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean, 'to be applied at runtime'?  This is very vague.  Everything is ultimately done at runtime.  Seems like you want to pass in a string and a method to another method, is that it?  Make a switch statement in your method and match the value of the format parameter and execute the corresponding method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx).  You can essentially implement what you're describing using it save for the parsing of the user supplied text.

The smiple example you've used there would be something like,

```
var method = "ToLower()";
var methodInfo = typeof(String).GetMethod(method);
var string = "foo";
string.GetType().InvokeMember(....);
```

Comment: How would i go about implementing Remove(1,4)

Comment: @wadapav you could use regex to remove the parameters, and then with reflection you pass the parameters as an object array. However, it would be difficult to tell what to cast the types as and you lose all compile time safety. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @James it is as James said, you'll need to use a Regex to parse the string and construct what you're after.  Parse out the method name, an array of parameters, and something to infer the type of what you are being parsed.  It is a lot of work if you're expecting to do this for completley free text.

Comment: I need to give the users the ability to decide what needs to be done with the string. I could conceivably write case statements

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an enum instead of the second string parameter. It will be helpful as for type safety.

```
public enum StringManipulationType
{
  ToLower,
  ToUpper
}
```

and then rewrite the manipulation method you had with the following:

```
private string Formatting(String data, StringManipulationType manipulationType)
{
  switch (manipulationType)
  {
    case StringManipulationType.ToLower:
      return data.ToLower();
    case StringManipulationType.ToUpper:
      return data.ToUpper();
    case default:
      throw new ArgumentException();
  }
}
```

In all the places where you had the earlier "string parameter", change it with enum like this:

Comment: If the OP knows the type of the method - and they would, if they're to define an Enum - why not just use a Func and pass it in? Besides, this doesn't accurately cover the cases where they need arguments for the method.

Comment: J.Steen - I still don't have an answer or code that I can use for my situation.

Comment: @wadapav And neither have you stated what you've tried, in your previous question. We do expect some effort, around here. =)

Comment: J.Steen - appreciate your help - please see above