# How to get class members values having string of their names?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I read the properties of a C# class dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/how-can-i-read-the-properties-of-a-c-sharp-class-dynamically)

I have to get values of class members using strings of their names only. I think I have to use Reflection but I am not realy sure how to. Can you help me?

Comment: I have one question before I can help - What are you talking about?  Can you post an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yep. We'll vote to close the question if you don't really provide any example of what you need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
MemberInfo member = typeof(MyClass).GetMember("membername");
```

[GetMember reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.type.getmember.aspx)

If you know type of member you're looking for, you can use `.GetMethod`, `.GetField`, `.GetProperty`, etc.

If you don't know the type you are working with:

```
var myobject = someobject;
string membername = "somemember";
MemberInfo member = myobject.GetType().GetMember(membername);
```

Different member types have different means to getting the value. For a property you would do:

```
var myobject = someobject;
string propertyname = "somemember";
PropertyInfo property = myobject.GetType().GetProperty(membername);
object value = property.GetValue(myobject, null);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
public class Foo
{
  public string A { get; set; }
}
public class Example
{
  public void GetPropertyValueExample()
  {
    Foo f = new Foo();
    f.A = "Example";
    var val = f.GetType().GetProperty("A").GetValue(f, null);
  }
}
```