# C# How to access a class member by Binding

Tags: c#, binding

I want to access a class member by binding, but without any UI nor XAML code.

```
class Foo {
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

class Bar {
    public Foo foo { get; set; }
}

Bar bar = new Bar() {
    foo = new Foo() {
        Value = 2
    }
}

Binding b = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("foo.Value");
b.Source = bar;

// Now I want a method which returns bar.foo.Value, would be like that:
int value = b.GET_VALUE(); // this method would return 2
```

Is there such a method ?

Comment: Have you read up on the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838207(v=vs.95).aspx)?

Comment: Yes, but the documentation is with XAML or user interface element (TextBlock)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks to:
[How to get class members values having string of their names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140168/how-to-get-class-members-values-having-string-of-their-names)

No need of Binding class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static object GetPropertyValue(this object Obj, string PropertyName)
    {
        object Value = Obj;

        foreach (string Property in PropertyName.Split('.'))
        {
            if (Value == null)
                break;

            Value = Value.GetType().GetProperty(Property).GetValue(Value, null);
        }

        return Value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Foo {
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

class Bar {
    public Foo foo { get; set; }
}

Bar bar = new Bar() {
    foo = new Foo() {
        Value = 2
    }
}

bar.GetPropertyValue("foo.Value"); // 2

bar.foo = null;
bar.GetPropertyValue("foo.Value"); // null
```