# Dynamically run "string" in c#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have a string that represents the value of a property of a control:

```
"objectControl.BackColor = Color.Black";
```

Is there any way to interpret and assign that value by code?

Thank you.
Best regards,
Fernando

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read the properties of a C# class dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/how-can-i-read-the-properties-of-a-c-sharp-class-dynamically)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse the color name using  a regular expression and then resolve the strong enumeration value of the same name using `Enum.Parse`.

I am not sure if you are using WPF or Windows Forms (or something else for that matter) so I will provide you an *adaptable* example using the `ConsoleColor` enumeration instead.

```
static void SetConsoleBackgroundColor(string statement)
{
    var colorName = Regex.Match(statement, "Color\\.(.+)").Groups[1].Value;
    var color = (ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof (ConsoleColor), colorName);
    Console.BackgroundColor = color;
}

static void Main()
{
    SetConsoleBackgroundColor("objectControl.BackColor = Color.Red");
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Update**

Given that you are using Windows Forms and that `Color` is a structure and not an enumeration -  use reflection to obtain the color property (instead of `Enum.Parse`).

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetBackColor("button1.BackColor = Color.Black");
}

public void SetBackColor(string statement)
{
    var controlName = Regex.Match(statement, "(.+?)\\.").Groups[1].Value;
    var colorName = Regex.Match(statement, "Color\\.(.+)").Groups[1].Value;

    // Todo: ensure that each of the aforementioned matches were successful.    

    var control = Controls.Find(controlName, true).FirstOrDefault();
    if (control == null) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Control X does not exist.");
    }

    var property = (Color) typeof (Color).GetProperty(colorName).GetValue(null);
    control.BackColor = property;
}
```

Comment: @ByteBlastÇ Thank you. I tried this (WinForm), but an error raises: "Type provided must be an Enum."

Comment: @FernandaB. Oh balls. `Color` is a `struct`. Hold on.

Comment: @FernandaB. Updated my answer bud.