# Compare object attribute from String

Tags: c#

Hi guys I need some like php eval function to run piece of code that is storage in the DataBase, like:

```
"UidAsLong == 18" or "Name.Equals('Visa')" .
```

So, I have to check if these piece of code match with an object, like PaymentInfo, so if PaymentInfo.UidAsLong == 18 the function may return true, or if the name equals Visa...

These piece of code in database can assume any C# attribute comparison expression, so, I need a function like CheckMatch(object payment, string stringToCheck) that returns me True or false.

Thanks

Comment: have a look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/how-can-i-evaluate-c-sharp-code-dynamically

Comment: In short, No.  You either need to a. write a parser or b. somehow compile your code snippets at runtime.  If you go with route b, [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) might be helpful to look into.

Comment: Or Dynamic Linq?